# Rails3 and Liquid initialize error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

Hi I have a Rails 3 app with the gem Liquid for templates. The problem is that I get this error with my custom tag. I will be using the example of the wiki.

In my /lib/ I created a random.rb for my custom tag

```
 class Random < Liquid::Tag

   def initialize(tag_name, max, tokens)
     super
     @max = max.to_i
   end

   def render(context)
     rand(@max).to_s
   end
end
```

In my initializers folder a liquid.rb for register that tag.

```
Liquid::Template.register_tag('random', Random)
```

In the console

```
@template = Liquid::Template.parse("{% random 5 %}")
```

And I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:28:in `initialize'
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:28:in `new'
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:28:in `parse'
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/document.rb:5:in `initialize'
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:58:in `new'
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:58:in `parse'
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:46:in `parse'
from (irb):14
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/Artau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

But if I type:

```
 1.9.3-p385 :004 > @template = Liquid::Template.parse("{{random 5}}")
 => #<Liquid::Template:0x007fa36b554108 @root=#<Liquid::Document:0x007fa36b553de8 @nodelist=[#<Liquid::Variable:0x007fa36b5536e0 @markup="random 5", @name="random", @filters=[]>]>>
```

And when I render:

```
 1.9.3-p385 :005 > @template.render
 => ""
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

I'm in Rails 3.2.13

Comment: try to rename your class, because in the standard ruby library there's already a class named Random

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo, that was the problem. It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename your class, because in the standard ruby library there's already a class named Random .